# Unhide sys says HIDDEN Processes Found: 1 but gives no further information

Tags: ubuntu, security

i checked 2 of my ubuntu systems with `sudo unhide sys`.

On both machines the result is
 `HIDDEN Processes Found: 1`

but unhide gives no further information no pid, nothing.

how can i investigate what's this about?

Answer (score 2):

1 means process ID (not the number of found processes).
So you can run:

```
ps aux
```

And check what is process with ID=1.

In my case:

```
root         1  0.0  0.0  23896  2056 ?        Ss   12:40   0:00 /sbin/init
```